# Smart way of error reporting into database

Tags: python, python-3.x, checksum

I'm developing a computerCheck program, it's Python based (for now).
The programs basically checks some Windows OS status, e.g. if the correct AV is running, if bitlocker is activated and so on....
The result of the check OK or NOT OK is reported into the database. However, since it's about 10 checks...I would like to report in a smart way back to the database. I don't want to have an entry for every check in the record, because this would be a problem when the number of checks change.
So I would like to send a "smart" kind of checksum...
The checksum should give which of the checks are NOT OK (e.g. check nr.1 is false, check nr.4 is false) and preferable a reason...like nr 1. status 2 (2 represents e.g. service not running..)

Now, the big question is, is it possible to do it that way, so e.g. always sending a x character long code to the database and when reading the code back, you can "unpack" it to something human readible again....

I hope it's clear what I'm looking for...

Thanks in advance!
/Jasper

Comment: Your question is very general and hard to answer. A [mre] of code would be best to understand your problem. Otherwise look at [ask] to better help you formulate your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a string where every index represents one check. You will have more than enough chars to use as states. For example:
`"0120"` -> check0 ok, check1 error state 1, check2 error state 2...

New checks can simply be appended to the string, removed checks need to be marked as no more existent:
`"0X200"` -> check1 doesn't exist anymore and one new check appended at the end.

Comment: so you mean like having a string with chunks of 4 characters per check...ex. AABBCCDD Where AA and CC are representing the check number and the BB and DD the state...that way I can have 99 checks with 99 states each....and just parse until end of string...?

Comment: @Jasper The check number would be defined by the position in the string, no need to store it explicitly. As state you can use at least all printable ASCII chars (about 90 I think).

Comment: then I don't fully understand...lets say I have check 1, error code is 3 and I have check 5 and error code is 3...how would the string look like in your case?

Comment: `30003` check1 and 5 have code 3, check 2, 3 and 4 have code 0

Comment: easier then I was thinking of! So I have 9 error codes for each check...which is more then sufficient! I'll start with this approach. Super, thanks very much @Wups!